# C# VSTO - How to save activesheet to a new worbook / new file?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm developing an Excel add-In with .NET 4.7.2. So, as the user uses this add-in, the actions of my programm coming almost always from GetInstance() function, which returns

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
```

The actual challenge is to save the activesheet as a new workbook/Excel file. I'm using Office.Interop.Excel like this at all classes

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

I've already tried a lot of ways to solve this, but nothing really worked.

**One: -----------------**

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Vorlage auswählen";
        ofd.InitialDirectory = Stx.DIRECTORY_VORLAGE;
        DialogResult ofdResult = ofd.ShowDialog();

        if (ofdResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Excel.Workbook activeBook = GetInstance();
            Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)GetInstance().ActiveSheet;
            string masterFile = activeSheet.Name + "_Master.xltx";

            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Title = "Speicherort neues Masterfile";
            sfd.InitialDirectory = Stx.DIRECTORY_MASCHINEN;
            sfd.FileName = masterFile;
            sfd.Filter = "Excel Template (*.xltx)|*.xltx";
            DialogResult sfdResult = sfd.ShowDialog();

            if (sfdResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strFileTemplate = ofd.FileName.Trim();
                string strNewFile = sfd.FileName.Trim();
                
                // copies the template .xltx to the destination
                System.IO.File.Copy(strFileTemplate, strNewFile);

                Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
                //Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(path, ReadOnly: false);
                //Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(strNewFile, 0, true, Type.Missing, "", "", false, Type.Missing, "", true, false, 0, false, false, false);
                Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Sheets[1];

                //Copy sheet to new Workbook
                activeSheet.Copy(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, sheet);

                // by the way, this is working (vice versa)
                //     sheet.Copy(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, nativeWorkbook.Sheets[nativeWorkbook.Worksheets.Count]);

                book.Save();
                book.Close();
                app.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```

I also tried it with .xlsx files, but this also didn't work.

For me it would be ok to copy the whole workbook and delete the unnecesary sheets, but this also didn't work.

**Two:-------------**

```
                string abc = activeSheet.Name;
                GetInstance().SaveAs(strNewFile, FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
                //GetInstance().SaveAs(strNewFile, FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLTemplate);

                Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(strNewFile, ReadOnly: false);

                foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in wb.Worksheets)
                    if (!sheet.Name.Equals(abc))
                        sheet.Delete();  // doesn't work

                wb.Save();
                wb.Close();
                app.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the winner is....
Open both workbooks with the same Application, copying will also work.

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Vorlage auswählen";
        ofd.InitialDirectory = Stx.DIRECTORY_VORLAGE;
        DialogResult ofdResult = ofd.ShowDialog();

        if (ofdResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)GetInstance().ActiveSheet;
            string fileType = ofd.FileName.Substring(ofd.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
            string masterFile = activeSheet.Name + "_Master" + fileType;

            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Title = "Speicherort neues Masterfile";
            sfd.InitialDirectory = Stx.DIRECTORY_MASCHINEN;
            sfd.FileName = masterFile;
            sfd.Filter = "Excel Template (*" + fileType + ")|*" + fileType + "";
            DialogResult sfdResult = sfd.ShowDialog();

            if (sfdResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strFileTemplate = ofd.FileName.Trim();
                string strNewFile = sfd.FileName.Trim();
                System.IO.File.Copy(strFileTemplate, strNewFile);
                
                Excel.Workbook destBook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Open(strNewFile, 0, false, Type.Missing, "", "", false, Type.Missing, "", true, false, 0, false, false, false);
                //destBook.Activate();
                Excel.Worksheet destSheet = destBook.Sheets[destBook.Worksheets.Count];
                activeSheet.Copy(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, destSheet);

                destBook.Save();
                destBook.Close();
            }
        }
```

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application in my case. What a damn bad stumbling block.

Answer (score 0):

You can try workbook.saveas method to save the active sheet to a new xltx file.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.InitialDirectory = "E:\\";
            DialogResult ofdResult = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (ofdResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                Excel.Workbook activeBook = app.Workbooks.Open(ofd.FileName);
                Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)activeBook.ActiveSheet;
                string masterFile = activeSheet.Name + "_Master.xltx";

                SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                sfd.InitialDirectory = "E:\\";
                sfd.FileName = masterFile;
                sfd.Filter = "Excel Template (*.xltx)|*.xltx";
                DialogResult sfdResult = sfd.ShowDialog();
                if (sfdResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string strFileTemplate = ofd.FileName.Trim();
                    string strNewFile = sfd.FileName.Trim();
                    activeBook.SaveAs(strNewFile, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLTemplate);
                    activeBook.Close(false);
                    app.Quit();
           
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
           
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried SaveAs a lot of times with different file types and arguments, but only the whole workbook was saved. Why should the active sheet be saved when u write workbook.SaveAs() ?

Comment: @prototype0815, as usual, the active sheet belongs to the workbook, so when we save the workbook, the worksheet should be saved automactically. By the way, have you tried my code? Is it work for you. If not, please tell me what is wrong with you.

Comment: Yes I tried your code, as I mentioned it saves the whole workbook exactly as my code. And yes, the active sheet is also inside the newly saved workbook. But this is not what I try to get. --> If you do it by hand, open an .xlsx with one or more sheets inside. Right click at the desired sheet, choose "move or copy...", now you can click copy to new workbook. This is what I want to solve programatically.